# Subquery in Junction Object, can't get relationship

Tags: soql

I've got a Junction Object, `Product_Dependencies_Association` which has a Mast-Detail Relationship to a `My_Custom_Product__c` Object named `Child_Product__c` and a *Lookup* relationship (not Master-Detail) that also points to a `My_Custom_Product__c` Object named `Parent_Product__c`.

The `Child_Product__c` relationship's `Child Relationship Name` is `Child_Product_Relationship`.

**My question is, why won't the following query work?**

```
[select (SELECT Name FROM Child_Product_Relationship__r) FROM Product_Dependencies_Association__c]
```

It fails with `Error:

> Compile Error: Didn't understand relationship
>   'Child_Product_Relationship__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.`

Interesting to note: https://workbench.developerforce.com reports the `relationshipName` for the `Child_Product__c` relationship as `Child_Product__r`, not `Child_Product_Relationship__r` as I defined within the Salesforce UI. I've also tried `Child_Product__r` and `Child_Product_Relationship` in the query and get the same error.

Details of the Child_Product field, as requested:
[image: Child Product field]

Comment: Loog at the field Child_Product__c and what does it say for the Child Relationship name. Could you have a type? Can you attach a screenshot of the field detail

Comment: @Eric, the Child Relationship Name is Child_Product_Relationship. I don't know what you mean by "Could you have a type?". Edited my question with screenshot you requested. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what Workbench shows under the Child Relationships for your Product_Dependencies_Association__c object?
I'm wondering if perhaps you have the relationshps mixed and Product_Dependencies_Association__c is on the Detail end of the Master/Detail relationship?

Comment: what is the plural name does it say Child Product Relationship (or) Child Product Relationships, try Child_Product_Relationships__r

Comment: @DougB, hm, there are no relevant Child Relationships for the Product_Dependencies_Association__c object. The child relationship does show up for the My_Custom_Product__c object. Should I flip them around, and if so how?

Comment: @rao, the plural version isn't working either.

Comment: Based on what you show and what you are trying to do the MD field may be on the wrong object, As it stands currently the Detail is Child_Product__c and the master is My_Custom_Product__c

Comment: My answer below should help in creating the M/D Relationship that you are looking for.  Remember the Object with the lookup field (M/D or otherwise) is always the child.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your screenshot I suspect "My_Custom_Project__c" is the parent in the relationship and Product_Dependencies_Association__c is the child in the relationship.

The below query should confirm this suspicion.

```
[SELECT Name (SELECT Name FROM Child_Product_Relationship__r) FROM My_Custom_Project__c ]
```

If this is was not your intent remove the "Child_Object__c" field from the "Product_Dependencies_Association__c" object.  Instead create it on the "My_Custom_Project__c" as a Master/Detail looking up to the "Product_Dependencies_Association__c" object

Comment: Yes, this works! It just seems superfluous to have to query the product when I don't care about the product. Unfortunately, I cannot add a Master/Detail Relationship to the `My_Custom_Project__c` object as it is a Managed Object.

Comment: @DavidMurdoch Glad I could help.

Answer (score 3):

The child relationship name "Child_Product_Relationship" is the name of the relationship to the `Product_Dependencies_Association__c` child records from the point of view of the `My_Custom_Product__c` parent record.

You're trying to use it from the opposite direction in your query which is why you're receiving the error about an unknown relationship name. That name exists on the parent (master: `My_Custom_Product__c`) and points to the list of its children (detail: `Product_Dependencies_Association__c`).

```
[SELECT Id
    , Name
    , (SELECT Id
          , Name 
       FROM Child_Product_Relationship__r) 
 FROM My_Custom_Product__c]
```

This query produces a list of `My_Custom_Product__c` records and a list of `Product_Dependencies_Association__c` children under each one of them. The list of these child records is referred to by the name `Child_Product_Relationship__r`.